# Raw SQL insert statement with optional parameter

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I'm trying to execute this command but get an exception:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Foo (Column1, Column2) 
                    values (@Parameter1, @Parameter2)";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parameter1", 'bar'));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parameter2", null));
```

The exception states that *@Parameter2* is expected but was not supplied.

Actually I'm providing it with *null* value. So how can I insert this very null into nullable *Column2*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to provide a `NULL` to the underlying database, use `DBNull.Value`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Adapt to whatever datatype your parameter really is (I'm just guessing here, since you didn't tell us - and I prefer to **always** explicitly tell the parameter what datatype it is)

Answer (score 2):

Use `DBNull.Value` to represent a `null` value to the database:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Foo (Column1, Column2) 
                    values (@Parameter1, @Parameter2)";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parameter1", 'bar'));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parameter2", DBNull.Value));
```